# Getting the error : Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns while joining 2 datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 2 datasets[ReconEntity] where ReconEntity is :

```
case class ReconEntity(rowId: String,
                       groupId: String,
                       amounts: List[Amount],
                       processingDate: Long,
                       attributes: Map[String, String],
                       entityType: String,
                       isDuplicate: String)
```

First Dataset looks like :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551021334|  rowId,C1|      false|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C3|       true|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

and the second dataset looks like :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

And I want the resultant to look like this :

```
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |rowId|groupId|            amount|processingDate|attributes|isDuplicate|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551021334|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C1|     G1|USD,10.00000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C1|       true|
     |   C2|     G2|USD,2.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C2|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011459|  rowId,C3|      false|
     |   C3|     G2|USD,6.000000000...|    1551011017|  rowId,C3|       true|
     +-----+-------+------------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

I am joining the 2 datasets using left join and if the rowId is not present in second dataset, I am marking the value of isDuplicate flag as false, otherwise the original value in the resultant dataset. The logic is:

```
inputEntries.as("inputDataset").join(otherEntries.as("otherDataset")
      .select(joinKey),
      Seq(joinKey), "left")
      .withColumn("isDuplicateFinal", when(col("otherDataset.rowId").isNull, TRUE).otherwise(col("inputDataset.isDuplicate")))
      .drop("otherDataset.isDuplicate")
      .select(
                col("inputDataset.rowId"),
                col("inputDataset.groupId"),
                col("inputDataset.amounts"),
                col("inputDataset.processingDate"),
                col("inputDataset.attributes"),
                col("inputDataset.entityType"),
                col("isDuplicateFinal").alias("isDuplicate")
              ).as[ReconEntity]
```

Here the joinKey is rowId.This logic is working fine in local, but when I am trying to run the spark job, Its failing due to:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 7 columns and the second table has 8 columns;
'Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#526, isDuplicateFinal#7810]
+- 'Project [rowId#4188, rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#526, CASE WHEN isnull(rowId#4188) THEN true ELSE isDuplicate#526 END AS isDuplicateFinal#7810]
   +- 'Project [rowId#4188, rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#526]
      +- 'Join LeftOuter, (rowId#247 = rowId#4188)
         :- SubqueryAlias inputDataset
         :  +- Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#526]
         :     +- Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, CASE WHEN (row_number#517 = 1) THEN false ELSE true END AS isDuplicate#526, row_number#517]
         :        +- Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#253, row_number#517]
         :           +- Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#253, row_number#517, row_number#517]
         :              +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(rowId#247, processingDate#250L DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS row_number#517], [rowId#247], [processingDate#250L DESC NULLS LAST]
         :                 +- Project [rowId#247, groupId#248, amounts#249, processingDate#250L, attributes#251, entityType#252, isDuplicate#253]
```

Not able to understand whether the UNION is hapenning while performing `as[ReconEntity]`  or any other operation and which a new column is being generated, since I am dropping after joining the 2 datsets.

Answer (score 1):

Even I am not sure where UNION is happening in this code. But, is `.select(joinKey)` required? can you try running once by removing it.

Comment: That worked, removing the select in join.

Comment: But the expected results are bit different. I am not very well versed with joins, can you tell me how the output of the left join of the above 2 datasets